# Restrict edits to records of object with 'Modify All' permissions

Tags: permissions

We are using an appExchange product in our solution that requires us to provide 'Modify All' access to Contacts for profiles that would be using the product. Our security model needs us to restrict one of these profiles from modifying contacts that they do not own. Is there any workaround where we can restrict edits to records not own by the user of a profile which has 'Modify All' access to the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you need to use validation rule for this use case.

Fire your validation error when following rule is true. Mention other suitable conditions like profile name and `NOT(ISNEW())`

```
 (OwnerId <>  $User.Id) && NOT(ISNEW() && $Profile.Name='yourProfileName')
```

Comment: And add the profile check to the rule since only applicable to one profile per OP

Comment: Thanks @Santanu Boral this worked for me after tweaking the condition a little bit to- (OwnerId <>  $User.Id) && NOT(ISNEW()) && ($Profile.Name='yourProfileName') ..